# Can't access to directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Why I can't access to directory /test if I'm the owner and I've got permissions to write and read?

[image]

If I want to read the content of /test directory I have to do it like root:

[image]

Because If I do it like user, I can't!!!:

[image]

Why?

Comment: I can't access to /test directory with cd test. The sysmte tell me that I haven't permission.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I access this folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10565367/608639)

Comment: The solution is the next answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Directories need to have the `x` (executable) permission as well, otherwise you get the behavior you experience.

So the solution is

```
$ chmod ugo+x test
```